# Using a Jekyll for loop in a different directory

Tags: ruby, jekyll, directory-structure

I am building my blog using Jekyll, and originally planned to only use Jekyll for the homepage. Because of this, I had created other non-changing html pages in their respective directories, and they work just fine. However, I've recently been thinking about making a *separate* page to list all posts I've made thus far, and would thus need to reference the "main" site's posts.

My project's structure looks like the following:

```
_includes/
    footer.html
    header.html
    sidebar.html
_layouts/
    default.html
    posts.html
_posts/
    ...
_site/
    ...
about/
    index.html
archive/
    index.html
css/
    style.css
resume/
    index.html
_config.yml
index.html
```

I would like to list all posts I've made in the archive/index.html page. I attempted this by doing the following:

```
...
<h2>The Archive.</h2>
{% for post in site.posts %}    
<h4><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
<p><small>{{ post.date | date: "%B %e, %Y" }}</small></p>           
{% endfor %}
...
```

However, that archive/index.html page only renders the above as text.

I have also tried creating an entirely new Jekyll directory structure inside the archive directory, but this doesn't seem to work either.

**How can I make it so that the archive/index.html page recognizes the for loop for listing all my site's posts?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forked your repo and this `archive/index.html` works well :

```
---
layout: default
---
<h2>The Archive.</h2>
{% for post in site.posts %}
<h4><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
<p><small>{{ post.date | date: "%B %e, %Y" }}</small></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah, forgot the Front Matter. This didn't exactly solve my problem because this *forced me* to use the default.html styling, but making a new layout should fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, just using the --- --- delimiters at the beginning of my html file allowed me to structure that one page exactly the way I liked it, and the for loop was still recognized.